# javascript eval method syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jquery in my web application. There we use the below eval method.

```
    var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

After googling I found eval method used above converts json data to javascript object. But what does that syntax means ? why it has to be enclosed within ('(' ')') parenthesis. Please help me in understanding.

Comment: "There we use the below eval method." ... **WHY?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `()` to enclose data is to prevent `{}` to be parsed as a block.

```
var json = eval('{}');  // the result is undefined
var json = eval('({})');  // the result is the empty object. 

var json = eval('{"a": 1}'); // syntax error
var json = eval('({"a": 1})'); // the result is object: {a: 1}
```

But you **should not use** `eval` to parse json data.

Use `var json = JSON.parse(data);` or some library functions instead.

Comment: `{a: 1}` is not valid JSON. That is actually parsed as a label `a` for an empty expression `1` in a block.

Comment: This is the correct answer as to why your string needs to be enclosed by the brackets. Though: `JSON.parse` is what you should use, except for IE<9 (doesn't support `JSON` out of the box. Not to worry: `$.parseJSON(data);` is X-browser, and since you're using jQuery already, why not use the latter?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval` to parse json. Since you're using jQuery, use `$.parseJSON(data)`. What if data contained `window.close()`?

WRT to the parentheses, you can see a comment explaining them in [douglas crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L467):

> ```
> // In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
> // JavaScript structure. The '{' operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
> // in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
> // in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.
> ```

Comment: Alternates to jQuery - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).